# Adding android:id to xml breaks entire app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:text="Disable Filter" android:background="@drawable/buttons" style="@style/ButtonText" android:layout_weight="25" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageFilter" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="75" />
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As soon as I add `android:id="@+id/btnFilterPreview"` to the `Button` my app stops working. Why is that?

Comment: Please define "stops working". If by "stops working" you mean that you have a crash, please examine LogCat to look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: By "stops working" I mean the app starts and displays a black screen then then it closes and says it has "Unfortunately stopped".

Comment: If by "stops working" you mean that you have a crash -- which apparently you do -- please examine LogCat to look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Please post the stack-trace of our crash if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans to solve the issue, Right click on the Project and and chose: `Clean and Build`

Comment: As @Ryan Naddy said, clean build the project. (And in eclipse, too.. If you changed some id or any of the property in xml, you must clean and build your project so that application will find references of all ids properly.)

Answer (score 0):

Clean Build your project so that all id is regenerate and application will find reference of new ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Same code of you . Running Perfect Without any changes.

I had `just Clean & Re-Build Project` Nothing else .

Try it.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFilterPreview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:text="Disable Filter" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageFilter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="75" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also be caused Android automatically adds `android.R` in its header file remove it

and then   `Build Project` Again

Answer (score 0):

Besides `Clean and Build`, make sure you do not have duplicate IDs.

Say you have another ImageView with the same ID, it could crash when some code like

`(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFilterPreview)`

is executed.